# Firefox - Single restricted window doesn't load Favicon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, favicon

I have a small code snippet which opens a new window ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) with restrictions (no address bar, title bar, scroll bars, a fixed height & width, etc).

When this new tab is opened, Favicon is not loaded in Firefox.

This works fine in Google Chrome & Edge ( haven't tried Safari, Opera).

Here's the [Code Pen example](https://codepen.io/swsessaji/pen/oNzEEqM).

```
const openNewWindow = function () {
  window.open(
    "http://www.google.com",
    "Gwindow",
    "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,top=50%,left=50%,height=500px,width=500px"
  );
};
```

[Here is the image of how this new window looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPxYK.png)

Run this on Edge, Firefox & Chrome & notice the favicon.

Firefox version - 84.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: How shall people test this by only having a static image?

Comment: @JavaScript I have added codepen link..